# Millennial ads only shows a huge white rectangle

Tags: android, eclipse, ads, millennial-media

I'm trying to implement Millennial media ads on my application. I have set it up via XML, but when I run the app, it only shows a white rectangle that takes up half the screen.

Also in my log I get an

```
Millennial ad return failed. Zero content lenght returned.
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainLay">

    <com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
        android:id="@+id/mmadview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:apid="APID"
        app:adType="MMBannerAdTop"
        app:refreshInterval="30"
        app:accelerate="true"
        app:ignoreDensityScaling="false"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Jason from Millennial Media. This should be fixed by correctly sizing your advertisement unit. Take a look at *[XML Layout](http://wiki.millennialmedia.com/index.php/Android#XML_Layout)*.

And you'll see that the XML includes:

```
app:height="60"
app:width="480"
```

This will constrain the advertisement so that it does not take over the screen and cause the SDK to ask our servers for the right size advertisement, which could solve your no response issue.

If you're still not seeing us fill your advertisement requests, or if you're having any other issues with the SDK, please do not hesitate to open a ticket at `https://support.mmedia.com/`.

Comment: None of the Millennial Media XML's example files consist such entries. Please elaborate on the issue